# Javascript - The context of apply

Tags: javascript

```
var MyModules = (function Manager() {
    var modules = {};

    function define(name, deps, impl) {
        for (var i=0; i<deps.length; i++) {
            deps[i] = modules[deps[i]];
        }
        modules[name] = impl.apply( impl, deps );
    }

    function get(name) {
        return modules[name];
    }

    return {
        define: define,
        get: get
    };
})();

MyModules.define( "bar", [], function(){
    function hello(who) {
        return "Let me introduce: " + who;
    }

    return {
        hello: hello
    };
} );
```

These are the snippets extracted from kyle Simpson's "You don't know JavaScript". However what confuses me is the usage of APPLY. Normally, when we set the context for apply, that is, THIS, the this or context is usually an object or array. But Kyle set it via the passed-in function and I have never seen it before and I am just wondering how it works. The snippet I am describing is this one: **modules[name] = impl.apply( impl, deps );**. Then I created the simplest snippet myself

```js
function func(par) {
  console.log(par);
}

func.apply(func, [1, 2, 3]); // 1
func.apply(null, [1,2,3]); // 1
```

It does not make any difference whether I pass in **func** or **null** as the first parameter for apply. I still get a value 1 displayed in console.

Comment: "value 1" - Did you mean `[1, 2, 3]`?

Comment: yes. the integer 1 within the array [1,2,3]

Comment: Oh wait, right of course... this is `apply` not `call`... Ok, try using `this` inside `func`. You'll see that `this` is different.

Comment: Since you don’t use `this` inside the function you call `apply` on, it makes absolutely no difference what the first argument of `apply` is. You might as well call `func.apply({ someRandomStuff: func.bind.call(func, Function.prototype.apply.call(Array, 3)) }, [ 1, 2, 3 ]);` or whatever. If the function passed to `MyModules.define` actually did use `this`, then it would indeed be the function itself. Whether this is _useful_ is an entirely separate question.

Comment: I think it helps to demystify `this` a little bit. When you use `impl.apply(impl, deps)` it is as if you simply call `impl(impl, ...deps);` (i.e. first argument is `impl` itself, rest arguments are the items of `deps`), but the (imaginary) definition of `impl` looks like `function impl(this, ...deps){`…`}` where `this` cannot be changed to something else. So `this` is like a parameter which you can use like a variable (which you cannot change). The value of `this` happens to be `impl`. _Why_ Kyle Simpson chose to use `impl`, of all things, as the value of `this` is not something I know.

Comment: so does this mean that we could pass anything as a context of apply? But still I am just wondering how the code works and why passing function as a context?

Comment: @kenryuakuma Yes, you can pass any value as the first argument to `.apply`; this value will then be usable as `this` in the function. A function is also just a value.